# App/Widget Height is zero on SAP Hana Cloud Portal

Tags: user-interface, sapui5

So I am building (a) webpage(s) using the *SAP Hana Cloud Portal*.

1. I have defined a template that looks roughly like this:

```xml
<mvc:View 
    controllerName="cpv2.templates.custom.Template" 
    height="100%" 
    xmlns:cpControls="sap.hana.uis.flp.control"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified" 
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <Page showFooter="false" showHeader="false" enableScrolling="true">
        <u:SplitContainer id="mySplitContainer" showSecondaryContent="false">
            <u:secondaryContent>
                <core:Fragment fragmentName="cpv2.templates.custom.SideNavigationPanel" 
                    type="XML" id="idSideNav"/>
            </u:secondaryContent>
            <u:content>
                <cpControls:Section alias="custom.shellHeader"></cpControls:Section>        
                <cpControls:Section alias="custom.header"></cpControls:Section> 
                <cpControls:Section alias="custom.content"></cpControls:Section>                        
                <cpControls:Section alias="custom.footerbanner"></cpControls:Section>                   
                <cpControls:Section alias="custom.footer"></cpControls:Section>
            </u:content>
        </u:SplitContainer>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

2. I then develop multiple SAPUI5 applications which I convert to *SAP Portal Components*. My app-widgets' views all have this basic format:

```xml
<mvc:View [namespaces, controller, etc.]>
    <App>
        <!-- most of them have VBox or HBox in their view -->
        <Vbox>
            <!-- some content here -->
        </VBox>
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

3. I deploy these applications to the Cloud Portal.
4. finally I create a webpage, use the above template and fill the defined sections with these app-widgets.

Now for some reason the height of these app-widgets are all *0*. Inspecting the page shows me they are there, but their height is rendered zero.
Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Can you verify the <App> object is there? The UI5 inspector for chrome is a decent tool for this, or otherwise hit `ctrl-shift-alt-p` and select diagnostics > control tree to verify the elements rendered (as ui5 elements, not html elements)

Comment: Yes, the app object is there.